# How to deploy realm object server to cloud foundry

Tags: node.js, realm, cloud-foundry

https://realm.io/docs/get-started/installation/developer-edition/

Seems like realm object server is base on nodejs, however I could not make it working.

By far, I could deploy it to cloud foundry successfully, but it just don't work.

Realm studio just hangs there.
[image]

Comment: Looks like you're trying to connect to port 80 while, by default, ROS listens to port 9080. Did you try connecting to `http://realm-boot-strap.cfapps.io:9080`?

Comment: Once you deployed to cloud foundry, it will provide a reverse proxy to internal port 8080. I have configured realm to run at port 8080 in cloud foundry container.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem when trying to connect to a Digital Ocean cloud ROS using port 9080.  The ROS is accessible in a browser but hangs in Realm Studio.

Answer (score 0):

apps to cloud foundry are deployed with the `cf push` command and they will run inside Linux Container. The contents of the linux container will put together by a buildpacks. Since realm is a NodeApp you should look at the NodJS buildpack documentation https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/node/node-tips.html

Apps running on Cloud Foundry container have an ephemeral disk therefore if your realm application needs a persistent disk you should not run it on a container in Cloud Foundry. Unless you have a Service Broker that can mount NFS volumes into the container.

Comment: Seems it works partially with web page, but I am not able to connect with realm studio.